# Porting LGPL code - what license can I use?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I have ported some LGPL code from Java to C#, which I plan to release as an open source component. Do I have to release my new library under LGPL too, or can I go with something less restrictive like MS-PL?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're basing your work on the original LGPL work, it seems to me that **your work is a derivative** of the original, and so section 2 of the license applies: Your code needs to be LGPL or, at your option, GPL. (The wording is different in versions 2 and 3, but it's the same section.) But I'm just a programmer, so what do I know? You're asking a question about the law, so your best course of action is to **ask a lawyer**.

Comment: For being honest, do lawyers understand software licensing right away? .

Comment: The layers who specialize in software licensing would understand it, although being honest shouldn't be their reason. If your lawyer doesn't understand software licensing, @Jaime, then consider hiring a different one.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you have to use LGPL:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License#Differences_from_the_GPL

It depends on whether your port is a derivative work (generally port == derivative work).